# .net Replace text with username at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, replace

I am writing a C# .net website for management use within my company. On this page, I have a location on the main page to hold notices, which are contextually colored information panels. On the options page, you are given the ability to create them by filling out a form containing the notification's title, message, and a drop down for its class.

One of the the options I would like to provide for the users is to use `{name}` within the message to show the username of the person viewing the notification. I attempted to use `message.Replace("{name}", "<asp:LoginName ID=\"LoginName1\" runat=\"server\" />");`, but this resulted in that exact string being posted as opposed to the .net parser converting it into the username.

I am using the default asp.net user creation engine and database, <s>though I've also heard that `Silverlight` is now the standard</s>.

As for my questions, would I be better off rebuilding the project in Silverlight, assuming Silverlight has the capability to handle secure logins? Also, what would be the correct way to go about replacing the username? Would I be better off with something like `{user=#}` where # is the user's ID? Theoretically, it would just be a database query from within my Notice class (the constructor calling a method that replaces bbcode with its html counterpart).

Thank you for your help

Comment: "though I've also heard that Silverlight is now the standard."  uh no, Silverlight has been discontinued since the release of Windows 8

Comment: Very good to know. Is there a new standard or is it back to asp.net?

Comment: I think ASP.NET MVC is the prime choice nowadays

Comment: Anyway, for your issue: `message.Replace("{name}", Page.User.Identity.Name)`

Comment: Awesome. I ended up using `message.Replace("{name}", "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);` because it was complaining about Page being a non-static member. Thanks for your help! If you'd like, go ahead and respond with an answer so you can get proper credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<asp:LoginName ID=\"LoginName1\" runat=\"server\" />` will work only if directly put in the ASPX. If you want to dynamically set the name without using a control, there's two way:

- From the page's code-behind, you can call `this.User.Identity.Name`
- From anywhere in the app, you can call `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`